# React Input Field logging empty string as first keystroke

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I have an input field for entering a search term and trying to filter results based on the search term. The problem is that the first value being passed is an empty string and input is offset by 1 item for each keypress after that. For example, if I type 'sea', it would update the search term to be ' se'. Then, when I try to delete the value, it is offset the other direction, so deleting ' se' ends with 's', which can't be deleted.

(Here's a link to the app in progress: https://vibrant-yonath-715bf2.netlify.com/allpokemon. The full search functionality isn't working quite yet. I'm pretty new at this.)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Pokemon from './Pokemon';

class PokemonList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pokemonList: [],
      searchTerm: '',
      fetched: false,
      loading: false
    };

    this.updateResults = this.updateResults.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    });
    fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          pokemonList: response.results,
          loading: true,
          fetched: true
        });
      });
  }

  handleSearchTermChange = (
    event: SyntheticKeyboardEvent & { target: HTMLInputElement }
  ) => {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: event.target.value });
    this.updateResults();
  };

  updateResults() {
    const filteredList = this.state.pokemonList.filter(
      pokemon =>
        pokemon.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.state.searchTerm.toUpperCase()) >= 0
    );
    console.log(this.state.searchTerm);
    this.setState({
      pokemonList: filteredList
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { fetched, loading, pokemonList } = this.state;
    let content;
    if (fetched) {
      content = (
        <div className="flex-grid">
          {pokemonList.map((pokemon, index) => (
            <Pokemon key={pokemon.name} id={index + 1} pokemon={pokemon} />
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    } else if (loading && !fetched) {
      content = <p> Loading ...</p>;
    } else {
      content = <div />;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          onChange={this.handleSearchTermChange}
          value={this.state.searchTerm}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search"
        />
        {content}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PokemonList;
```

Answer (score 2):

`setState` is asynchronous, so your `this.state.searchTerm` is not updated when you call `updateResults`. You could e.g. filter the array in render instead.

**Example**

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    pokemonList: [
      { name: "pikachu" },
      { name: "bulbasaur" },
      { name: "squirtle" }
    ],
    searchTerm: ""
  };

  changeSearchTerm = event => {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { pokemonList, searchTerm } = this.state;
    const filteredList = pokemonList.filter(pokemon =>
      pokemon.name.toUpperCase().includes(searchTerm.toUpperCase())
    );

    return (
      <div>
        <input value={searchTerm} onChange={this.changeSearchTerm} />
        {filteredList.map(pokemon => <div>{pokemon.name}</div>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I originally had it in the render function, but I assumed it was cleaner to pull it out into a separate function. Is this not the case with React? I'm happy to learn best practices as I get more familiar with the framework. :)

Comment: @SilasOtoko No problem! You could certainly keep a `filteredList` in state as well if you would prefer, it's more a question of taste. Just be careful so that you don't override the `pokemonList` in your state, since then you will not be able to remove your filter.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you call `this.updateResults();`
and then calling `this.setState({ searchTerm: event.target.value });` instead of using the callback function for `setState`.

For example:

```
this.setState({ searchTerm: event.target.value }, () => this.updateResults());
```

Hope I got it right.

Update:

Also I see many problems in your code, for example, why you update the list with a filtered list? you don't need to do that:

```
this.setState({
  pokemonList: filteredList
});
```

Instead of updating the results in the state, you simply need to render the filtered list... meaning your state stay with the original list, also your filterd `value`, just in the render you pass the filtered list..

Comment: Thanks! I know it's a mess right now. I'm doing this project as a learning project, and my approach is to make it work first, then go back and write it better. I appreciate the insight into how I can write it more efficiently! :)